# Display an alert if browser dosen't support code

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser

I want to display an alert if browser doesn't support code. Example: [my profile](http://www.designer-aman.com/)

Firefox 20 doesn't support it, so there should be an alert that says

> "Your Browser doesn't support this website, please upgrade Your
>   Browser"

What code do I have to add to show this alert?

Comment: Make an effort first and post the code

Comment: Do you seriously worry about Firefox... 20?

Comment: Embedded the link + extra minor formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to find out what browser the user is using and display the alert when needed.

`if(/regEx/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )` where regEx is a regular expression to detect the browsers you don't support